Problemas al cargar una tabla dinámica con javascript
**Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de ejecutar este código. Su función es crear una tabla dinámica dependiendo del usuario que se haya seleccionado, pero a la hora de ejecutar el login, se queda cargando hasta que muestra un error del servidor web (Error 504). Comentando la entrada del Javascript y quitando la llamada tampoco ha funciona para al menos sacar algún tipo de error, la pantalla no llega a cargar el único error que he podido recoger ha sido el siguiente:
*97 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /panel_admin.php?login=success HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.3:9000", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/
**
El código es el siguiente:
panel_admin.php
<?php
include('tiempo_usuarios.php');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.html");
    exit();
}

require_once "conexion.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trabajos programados</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prime-styles-admin.css">
    <script src="tabla_dinamica.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gi-navbar">
        <!-- Botón de cerrar sesión -->
        <div class="gi-row-end">
            <h2 class="h2-head">Bienvenido <?php echo "$username" ?></h2>
            <form action="logout.php" method="POST" class="logout">
                <button class="gi-button" type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="gi-panel-container">

        <div class="gi-panel-container--content">
            <div class="width-100 d-flex flex-center">
                <h2 class="gi-title">Trabajos programados</h2>
            </div>
            <h2>Seleccionar Usuario:</h2>
            <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="cargarTabla(); return false;">
                <select name="usuario_seleccionado">
                    <option value="">Seleccionar Usuario</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>"><?php echo $usuario; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Mostrar Tabla</button>
            </form>
            <!-- Aquí se insertará la tabla dinámica -->
            <table id="tablaDatos">
                <!-- Aquí se insertarán las filas de datos -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gi-footer">
        <!-- <img src="./imgs/fondo.jpg" alt=""> -->
        <div class="gi-background-mid"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>`





obtener_datos_usuario.php
<?php

// Requerir el archivo de conexión a la base de datos
require_once "conexion.php";

// Obtener el usuario seleccionado del parámetro GET
$usuario_seleccionado = $_GET['usuario'];

// Preparar la consulta para obtener los datos del usuario seleccionado
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT usuario_id, tarea, descripcion FROM tareas WHERE usuario_id = (SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario_seleccionado);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();

// Crear un array para almacenar los datos del usuario
$datos_usuario = array();

// Iterar sobre los resultados y almacenarlos en el array
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos_usuario[] = $row;
}

// Convertir el array a formato JSON
echo json_encode($datos_usuario);

// Cerrar la conexión y terminar el script
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();`

tabla_dinamica.js

// Función para cargar la tabla dinámica
function cargarTabla() {
    // Obtener el valor seleccionado del usuario
    var usuarioSeleccionado = document.querySelector("select[name='usuario_seleccionado']").value;
    // Hacer una solicitud AJAX para obtener los datos del usuario seleccionado
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "obtener_datos_usuario.php?usuario=" + usuarioSeleccionado, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Limpiar la tabla existente
            var tabla = document.getElementById("tablaDatos");
            tabla.innerHTML = "";
            // Crear una fila para los encabezados de la tabla
            var encabezados = ["Usuario_id", "Tarea", "Descripcion"]; // Ajusta los encabezados según tu estructura de datos
            var encabezadoRow = tabla.insertRow();
            for (var i = 0; i < encabezados.length; i++) {
                var cell = encabezadoRow.insertCell();
                cell.textContent = encabezados[i];
            }
            // Parsear los datos recibidos como JSON
            var datos = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            // Iterar sobre los datos y agregarlos a la tabla
            for (var j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow();
                fila.insertCell().textContent = datos[j].usuario_id; // Ajusta según la estructura de tus datos
                fila.insertCell().textContent = datos[j].tarea; // Ajusta según la estructura de tus datos
                fila.insertCell().textContent = datos[j].descripcion; // Ajusta según la estructura de tus datos
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

// Agregar un controlador de eventos para el evento submit del formulario
document.getElementById('miFormulario').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    // Prevenir la acción por defecto del formulario
    event.preventDefault();

    // Llamar a la función para cargar la tabla
    cargarTabla();
});`

Alguien me puede echar un cable?

Necesitaba que la tabla mostrara los valores que necesito sin que me de error en el propio login. El login está comprobado que funciona.


el error que se ve es el resultado de un request que ha sobre pasado el tiempo de  ejecucion / espera por una respuesta de parte del modulo php... en pocas palabras ... xhr.open como solucionarlos: tienes que debuggear obtener_datos_usuario.php  y ver que demora en la ejecucion hasta que punto llega...

Me pregunto por qué escribes esta consulta así: "SELECT usuario_id, tarea, descripcion FROM tareas WHERE usuario_id = (SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE username = ?)" en vez de hacer un JOIN, es decir: "SELECT t.usuario_id, t.tarea, t.descripcion FROM usuarios AS u INNER JOIN tareas AS t ON u.id=t.usuario_id WHERE u.username = ?". El JOIN garantiza que se usen los índices de las tablas, optimizando la consulta, asumiendo que las tablas está correctamente indexadas. Si el código sigue fallando debes verificar que la consulta funciona con fluidez probando directamente en la b. de datos
